# jQuery is not working with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I created simple .aspx form and it looks like the next jQuery code is not working.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
       alert("test");
     });
  </script>
```

I don't know if it is because of `Page_Load` on the server-side or something else.

Comment: Do you see any error on the browser's console?

Comment: Do you have include the jQuery library ?

Comment: Did you include jquery library:<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script> include this script tag in your page.

Comment: Add the content where u added this code.Is it in the head section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting '$' is undefined error.because for using jquery in your code you have to reference a jquery library file like below:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("test");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ops, I forgot that XD, Thank you so much for all of your efforts, and i'm so sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: its ok.that thing happen afterall we are human beings.

Comment: @BlackSheep I am using Vs 2010 so Jquery 1.4.1 comes inbuilt.

Comment: Well, that doesn't mean that you should suggest it to newbies, right?

Comment: @BlackSheep it is not good to download from jquery and implement in the code.for that you have inbuilt microsoft gives you so we use it.

Comment: Using CDN is good, jQuery 1.4.1 is too old, I'm not ASP developer and I haven't used the mentioned software, they could add the latest version instead of a specific one. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

Answer (score 3):

please check you pass jquery library in the head correctly.

```
<head runat="server">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Thanks

Comment: dear if you use asp.net and your head is runat="server" then you will use ~/ if you will not use this then you will pass complete url

Comment: and way you give me -1 its working for asp.net

Comment: if you have no knowledge of any thing its not mean that it will not work

Comment: I didn't -1 you :S , anyway thx for your help :D

Comment: I double check it and is not working for me!. The symbol `~/` is not translated by him self. I do not know if you have other module that is translated it automatically on header, but for me is not working as it is (sorry).

Comment: You should remove the ~ as it is incorrect in this scenario as it is resolved as a client-side reference

Comment: the ~ in asp.net mean root but for making it work you must write the runat="server" property

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have include jquery library file

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
```